# How to pass data from collection view to table view class?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

Here I am having a model class in which from this I need to pass selected sku value from collection view to table view in another class can anyone help me how to implement this ?

Here is the code for didselect item at index path method

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // Here you can check which Collection View is triggering the segue
    if collectionView == firstCategory {

    } else if collectionView == secondCategory {
        // from other CollectionView
    }else if collectionView == newCollection{
        newPassedSku = newModel[indexPath.item].sku as? String
        print(newPassedSku)
    }else{

    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "firstCategorySegue" {
        _ = segue.destination as! ProductListViewController
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "secondCategorySegue" {
        _ = segue.destination as! ProductListViewController
    }else if segue.identifier == "newSegue"{
        let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! ProductDetailsViewController
        detailsViewController.index = newPassedSku
        print(newPassedSku)
    }
    else {
        _ = segue.destination as! ProductDetailsViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: `func prepare(for segue` is being called?

Comment: it is calling but unable to pass my value @Mr.Bista

Comment: `if segue.identifier == "newSegue"{` condition is satisfied?

Comment: i tried a new code but wat happens before calling `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` this method it is calling first `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` so passing nil value in it @Mr.Bista

Comment: yes it satisfied @Mr.Bista

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly when u need to pass data from model class

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "firstCategorySegue" {
            _ = segue.destination as! ProductListViewController
        }
        else if segue.identifier == "secondCategorySegue" {
            _ = segue.destination as! ProductListViewController
        }else if segue.identifier == "newSegue"{
            let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! ProductDetailsViewController
            let indexPaths = self.newCollection.indexPathsForSelectedItems
            let indexPath = indexPaths?[0]
            let obj = newModel[(indexPath?.row)!]
            detailsViewController.index = obj.sku as! String
            print(obj.sku)
        }
        else {
            _ = segue.destination as! ProductDetailsViewController
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made direct segue from the Collection Cell instead of from ViewController. That is why the `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method is called before `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt`.

So you basically do need to make your segue from View Controller to the next View Controller.

Then you have to call the segue manually like:
`self.prepare(for: "segueIdentifier", any: nil)` inside `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectIt` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == newCollection{
        newPassedSku = newModel[indexPath.item].sku as? String
        print(newPassedSku)
        self.prepare(for: "segueIdentifier", sender: newPassedSku)
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "newSegue"{
        guard index = sender as? String else {
            return //do not segue if index is not valid
        }
        let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! ProductDetailsViewController
        detailsViewController.index = index
        print(newPassedSku)
    }
}
```

Comment: But how to pass value here ?

Answer (score 0):

[image] You need to make your segue directly from your collectionview controller to tableview controller, you are calling it from collectionview cell hence prepareforsegue is getting called first

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if collectionView == newCollection{
    newPassedSku = newModel[indexPath.item].sku as? String
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondCategorySegue",
                      sender: nil)
}
```

}

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier == "newSegue"{
    let detailsViewController = segue.destination as! ProductDetailsViewController
    detailsViewController.index = newPassedSku
}
```

}

Comment: it is passing nil value

Comment: but here in this view controller i am having 4 collection views and a view so how can i pass segue as u said

Comment: @user provide image of your Storyboard